# JSON Feed Won't Display in Tableview

Tags: json, swift, api, uitableview

I'm having trouble displaying data in a tableview. I know I'm reaching the data, because of the print function I have set up, displaying the data is a different story. For reference, this is a JSON feed coming from and API, listed here at https://api.opendota.com/api/rankings. If anyone has any advice, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

struct PlayerStatsParent:Decodable{
    let rankings: [PlayerStats]
}

//Optional objects are defined using ?
struct PlayerStats:Decodable {
    let personaname: String?
    let score: Double?
    let solo_competitive_rank: Int?
    let avatar: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var rankTable: UITableView!

    var rank = [PlayerStats]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //this is an optional URL, so need to define objects in contains
        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.opendota.com/api/rankings"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            //let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            //print(dataAsString)

            do{
                let downloadedRank = try JSONDecoder().decode(PlayerStatsParent.self, from: data)
                self.rank = downloadedRank.rankings
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.rankTable.reloadData()
                }
                print(downloadedRank.rankings)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error jsonErr", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.opendota.com/api/rankings"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rank.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rankCell") as? RankTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.nameLabel.text = rank[indexPath.row].personaname

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Did you check how many rows rank.count returned?

Comment: The code looks correct. Force-unwrap the cell to detect a design error : `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rankCell", for: indexPath) as! RankTableViewCell`

Comment: @vadian Agreed. Showing a blank cell via the `guard` is a slower way to find a development bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've set your UITableView delegate and dataSource in your storyboard you need to do so in `viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
self.rankTable.delegate = self
self.rankTable.dataSource = self
```

Otherwise your tableview has no way of getting data.

Comment: You don't need to do this if it is all connected in the storyboard.

Comment: This fixed my problem, but I do believe rmaddy is also correct.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my comment to include both options.